# How to create a trigger for before/after delete with update/insert in mysql?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables like as:

```
fee_master(id,cTId,feeType,amount,startDate,lastDate,fine_last_date,fine,status) 
payroll(id,emId,date,loan,netSalary)
```

I am trying to create a trigger like as:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test
DELIMITER $$;
 CREATE TRIGGER test
    BEFORE DELETE ON fee_master
    FOR EACH ROW
          UPDATE payroll SET loan=OLD.amount,netSalary=OLD.fine WHERE id=18;
DELIMITER $$;

delete from fee_master where id='18';
```

When I have run this trigger, the data is deleted from fee_master, but payroll is not updated, also I have tried to insert payroll but not working.Every times the data is deleted from fee_master.

If I change the update and delete query position with trigger then It is ok. Actually, It is not working on trigger operation.
What is the problem ?

Comment: What is the relation between `fee_master` and `payroll` tables? Is the `id` column of both tables, the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are new on triggering.

According to your question, I recommend you first read basics of triggering from here http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/

Remind that, It is a stored process. You do not need to run the trigger every times,I hope you are confuse here. After creating a trigger, You have to run the master query then the trigger automatically run the next operation.

Your code is ok. And the code of Barmar also ok.The main problem your understanding.

Comment: Your assumption is right. I was not clear about triggering. According to your link, I have understood but Delimiter is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for `UPDATE` is incorrect. Multiple assignments are separated by `,`, not `AND`.

```
UPDATE payroll SET loan=OLD.amount, netSalary=OLD.fine WHERE id=18;
```

Comment: I have fixed my question. But yet it is not working.